# how to put filtration in first order in left column magento

Tags: magento-1.9, sidebar, column

I want to change the magento left column block. I have

1. Compare products
2. Community poll
3. filtration
4. My Cart

i want to change the order's to

1. Filtration
2. Compare products
3. my cart
4. community poll

My working website : http://m.machinetoolsemart.com/welding-machine/tig-welder.html

Can you guide me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd study your layout frontend files

Check for `<reference name="left">` tag, and play with `before` and `after` parameters to get your desired order

Comment: <reference name="left">
<!-- Compare product -->  
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="-" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
<!-- Community poll -->               
            <block type="poll/activePoll" name="right.poll" after="-">
                <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/active.phtml</template><type>poll</type></action>
                <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/result.phtml</template><type>results</type></action>
            </block>
        </reference>

Comment: my xml content, here compare product and community poll , filtration xml code not present but it will show on after these two. i want to move filtration at first order.

Comment: it's working, my working xml code:<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>

Comment: Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 2):

Usage of options `before` and `after` for blocks in the layout may help, when all your blocks are called with one method `getChildHtml()` without mentioning block name. Or the block that contains your blocks is the class core/text_list exemplar (in the words, blocks should be inside). In other cases, `before` and `after` won’t has any influence., It is difficult to provide you with a ready solution, because you are using custom theme that differs from the base one. I can only give you a piece of advice to try using options `before` and `after`. If they failed to give the result (don’t forget to clear cash before testing) you should deal with the templates.

Don’t forget to check the attributes `before` and `after` for each of the blocks for the attributes with the `”-"` value.

In the rwd theme you can add the following to the class `local.xml`:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" before="-" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Block should be displayed after filters anyway, because filters are added to the block `left_first`:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left_first">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
```

It always called before `left`.

You can receive the full answer if you complete your question with your layout and template.